# Rubocop indentation configuration

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I would like rubocop to always only indent once. Also else, elsif and end shouldn't be indented at all. So something like this:

```
@shop = api
        .shop('de')['storefronts']
        .find_all do |front|
          front['name'] == 'WeeklyStorefront' ||
            front['name'] == 'DailyStorefront'
        end
        .map { |front|  font['catalogEntries'] }
        .flatten
        .map { |item| item['devName'] }
```

should look like this:

```
@shop = api
  .shop('de')['storefronts']
  .find_all do |front|
    front['name'] == 'WeeklyStorefront' ||
      front['name'] == 'DailyStorefront'
  end
  .map { |front|  font['catalogEntries'] }
  .flatten
  .map { |item| item['devName'] }
```

and this:

```
mode = if key.include? '_p2'
         'Solo'
       elsif key.include? '_p10'
         'Duo'
       else
         'Squad'
       end
```

should look like this:

```
mode = if key.include? '_p2'
  'Solo'
elsif key.include? '_p10'
  'Duo'
else
  'Squad'
end
```

I tried a lot of different config options but I never got it to work properly.

I tried:

```
Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation:
  EnforcedStyle: indented
```

that produces:

```
@shop = api
  .shop('de')['storefronts']
  .find_all do |front|
          front['name'] == 'WeeklyStorefront' ||
            front['name'] == 'DailyStorefront'
        end
  .map { |front| front['catalogEntries'] }
  .flatten
  .map { |item| item['devName'] }
```

and

```
mode = if key.include? '_p2'
             'Solo'
           elsif key.include? '_p10'
             'Duo'
           else
             'Squad'
end
```

which is better but still not what i wanted.

Comment: no one wants to visit those imgur links, posts all the code here.

Comment: Impossible to format the code correctly in this editior. Also couldn't add images either

Comment: "Impossible to format the code correctly" - no, any formatting is possible here. Try indenting your code blocks with 4 spaces (instead of surrounding each line with backticks or whatever it is you tried)

Comment: I have added the formatted code now. Please check how I did this (by clicking on *Edit* below your question) so that you can do it on your own next time :)

Comment: @holgerjust did you just... type all this code? You're a better man than I am. :)

Comment: ah okay i see, thanks!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev then all of us

Comment: It's my free Friday today :) Next time I hopefully don't have to do this again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the option [`Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation) in your `.rubocop.yml` file to enforce a different style for multiline expressions in your first example.

For your second example, you can configure [`Layout/MultilineAssignmentLayout`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Layout/MultilineAssignmentLayout) and [`Layout/EndAlignment`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Layout/EndAlignment).

```
Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation:
  EnforcedStyle: indented

Layout/MultilineAssignmentLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: same_line

Layout/EndAlignment:
  EnforcedStyleAlignWith: variable
```

Comment: i tried this already, didn't change anything. What did kinda help was MultilineMethodCallIndentation. But that only kinda works for the first example

Comment: (I originally used the wrong option in the example, see my current edit.)

Comment: this still doesn't properly work. I updated my answer with the results

Comment: ok nice, that works for the first example. on the second example the elsif and else are still indented

Comment: ok i got it to work now with Layout/EndAlignment:
  EnforcedStyleAlignWith: variable

Comment: Upvoted for the answer, but also the stellar editing of the question :)

Comment: @FallenPentagon You are right, that fixes it completely. I added the setting to my answer.